# How to use eslint rule for no-multi-comp

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I came across this [style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#basic-rules) and trying to adopt some of its rules.

The first rule mentioned about

> Only include one React component per file. However, multiple
>   Stateless, or Pure, Components are allowed per file. eslint:
>   react/no-multi-comp.

So in my `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
       "no-set-state": "off"
    },

    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true,
          "modules": true
      }
  },
  "globals": {
    "localStorage": true,
    "fetch": true
},
  "settings": {
    "react": {
        "pragma": "React",
        "version": "16.4.1"
    }
    }
}
```

I added this to `rules`

```
"rules": {
   "no-set-state": "off",
   "react/no-multi-comp":  [true, { "ignoreStateless": true }]
},
```

Am I doing this correctly? Because when i read the [docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-multi-comp.md#rule-options), I saw a `<enabled>` I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio Code, and installing the ESLint plugin, you should be able to look under Output  > ESLint

[image]

That the `<enabled>` is looking for 0, 1, or 2.

Change accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`<enabled>` looks for value one of the `0,1,2` or one of the `off,warn,error` meaning:

From the [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules):

> "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
>
> "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
>
> "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when
> triggered)

Comment: sure! here it is:https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 19, the path to this ".eslintrc" file can be found at: Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Linting. You can set the value of "react/no-multi-comp" property under "rules" as described in the answer.